# Remote SQL Server connection in C# and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I can't get a connection between C# and SQL Server.

I have two Windows servers (1 with SQL Server, 1 with the application).

I get this error:

> **System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException**: The underlying provider failed on Open
>
> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**:
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I think there is something wrong with my connection string...

The setup worked on localhost with 0 problems.

I have a 1:1 copy of the SQL Server database on my server.

I have a two Windows server setup. I already opened the inbound rules port 1433 on the ms sql server and opened the outbound port 1433 for application server. I added the user in SQL Server and tried different connection strings. I don't know what's wrong.

Please help
best regards

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="XXX_DATA_DEVEntities4" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.csdl|res://*/Entities.ssdl|res://*/Entities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX\Servername\MSSQL2017STD;initial catalog=XXX_DATA_DEV; Persist Security Info=False;User ID=usernam;Password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: "Data Source" looks strange, it should be either in the form of either "data source=server" or "data source=server\instance" imho

Comment: Yes I think there is the problem, so what it has to look like, 
I also tried this way: data source=servername\MSSQL2017STD; also didn't work.
I ithink he can't connect without ip address, am I right?

Comment: It depends on your network and server configuration. can you connect to the server from your workstation with sql server management studio?
Additionally you can check if tcp/ip protocol on the server configuration is enabled

Comment: yes tcp/ip is activated. No I can't establish a connection because I dont't know what I need to put in the field servername in sql server management studio.
Do I need to put servername/MSSQL2017STD or do I need to put IP-address in it?

Comment: it should be the same as data source

Comment: Check sql server configuration settings->protocols for that instance - if names pipes and TCP/IP are disabled, or Sql server browser service is not running - you'll get that error.

Comment: can you ping the server?

Comment: @theCryptoGuy388 have you tried adding an inbound rule for the port on the sql server machine (port 1433) under firewall setting?

https://consignor.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000647774-Opening-Windows-Firewall-for-client-connections-to-server

Comment: `XX.XXX.XXX.XXX\Servername\MSSQL2017STD` doesn't look like a valid data source.  You would use the IP *or* the server name, not both.  Do you have a named instance installed on that server?

Comment: Here is a good trouble shooting answer to a similar question: [Why am I getting “Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18060818/1260204)

Comment: I hope, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57510191/6598234) with another similar question would help you..

Comment: I tried everything you posted, I dont get this problem solved.
I can't ping to this server tcp-port 1433 is open and udp port 1434 also.
Also Telnet dont get a connection. Don't know what can I do now...
How can I find the problem?

Comment: @theCryptoGuy388  How these two server are connected with each other ?

Comment: @WamiqRehman at the moment the two servers are not connected. Do I need to connect them over vpn tunnel?